# Removing While Loop in String Search Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, while-loop, set-based

I have a query that takes one record from `#itemtemp`, and locates all entries from `ReportCSharp` that match, inserting those matches into the `#link_table`.   At present, the query runs in 7.5 min, which appears slow for iterating over only 1458 records in the `#itemtemp` table.

```
DECLARE 
    @num    int
,   @path   varchar(100)
,   @output varchar(100)
,   @max    int

SET @num = 1

SET @max = (SELECT max(num) FROM #itemtemp)

WHILE @num < @max
BEGIN

    SET @path = (SELECT path from #itemtemp where num = @num)

    INSERT INTO #link_table
    SELECT 
        itemId
    ,   Path
    ,   @path
    FROM ReportCsharp
    WHERE Script like '%"' + @path + '"%' 

    SET @num += 1
END
```

How can I remove the `WHILE` loop and replace with more set based operations?

Comment: What DBMS are you using? MySQL, Sql Server.. etc.

Comment: Watch out, you're missing the last row

Comment: Did you try to INNER JOIN the two tables?

Comment: the Script, column on  `WHERE Script like '%"' + @path + '"%' ` is a code script of potentially hundreds of URLs, the `@path` is just one URL I am searching for a match for

Comment: Why the min and max numbers?  Is there something you're trying to restrict?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO #link_table
    SELECT rcs.itemId,
           rcs.Path,
           it.Path
        FROM ReportCsharp rcs
            INNER JOIN #itemtemp it
                ON rcs.Script LIKE '%' + it.Path + '%';
```

Answer (score 0):

as appears in the code, you could do it directly with `insert...select...join`:

```
INSERT INTO #link_table
SELECT 
    P.itemId
,   P.Path
,   I.path
FROM ReportCsharp P
JOIN #itemtemp I ON P.Script like '%' + I.path + '%'
```